# Python function not defined

Tags: python, function

I have been making a python 3d game in ursina. So far so good but for one error:

````
  File "C:\Users\my name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\ursina\main.py", line 117, in _update
    __main__.update()
  File "c:\Users\my name\Desktop\game456.py", line 14, in update
    release()
NameError: name 'release' is not defined```
````

I dont understand this error. I have seen others run code like this too. This code is inspired by another person making a game in ursina so i copied a little bit of code myself. i tried googling an answer but it's just about a variable not being defined,etc. View code below.

```
from ursina import*
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController

gamebyme = Ursina()

def update():
    if held_keys["left mouse"]:
        shoot()
    else:
        release()

class Voxel(Button):
    def __init__(self, position = (0,0,0)):
        super().__init__(
            parent = scene,
            position = position,
            model = 'map',
            origin_y = 0.5,
            texture = texture,
            color = color.color(0,0,random.uniform(0.9,1)),
            scale = 0.1)

class Gun(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            parent=camera.ui,
            model='ak_47',
            position=Vec2(0.8,-0.1),
            color=color.gray,
            scale=0.3)

    def shoot(self):
        self.rotation=Vec3(0,0,10)
    def release(self):
        self.rotation=None
    def reload(self):
        self.rotation=Vec3(0,0,0)

plr = FirstPersonController()
gun = Gun()
vxl = Voxel()

gamebyme.run()
```

Comment: Have you defined `release` and `shoot` functions ?

Comment: Those are methods of `Gun`, so try `gun.release()` and `gun.shoot()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this function

```
def update():
    if held_keys["left mouse"]:
        shoot()
    else:
        release()
```

you should specify the Gun type object you want to call the functions from, eg:

```
def update(gun):
    if held_keys["left mouse"]:
        gun.shoot()
    else:
        gun.release()
```